# DBMS.OUTPUT.PUT_LINE prints null value in first iteration of loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I am trying to output increment values for each row in a dataset. For some reason every row except the first row prints a numeric value.

```
DECLARE CURSOR active_invoices_curs IS 
 SELECT vendor_id, invoice_date, sum(invoice_total) as sum_invoice
 FROM active_invoices
 GROUP BY vendor_id, invoice_date 
 ORDER BY vendor_id ASC; 
 last_vendor_id active_invoices.vendor_id%TYPE;
 last_invoice_total_sum active_invoices.invoice_total%TYPE;
 invoice_row active_invoices_curs%ROWTYPE; 
 invoice_increment number;
BEGIN
 FOR invoice_row in active_invoices_curs LOOP
  IF invoice_row.vendor_id != last_vendor_id OR invoice_row.vendor_id IS NULL THEN
   invoice_increment := invoice_row.sum_invoice;
  ELSE
   invoice_increment := invoice_row.sum_invoice - last_invoice_total_sum;
  END IF;
  last_vendor_id :=invoice_row.vendor_id;
  last_invoice_total_sum := invoice_row.sum_invoice;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('vendor '||invoice_row.vendor_id||'''s increment on '||invoice_row.invoice_date||' is: '||invoice_increment);
 End Loop;
End;
```

Expected Output:

vendor 37's increment on 17-MAY-14 is: 116

vendor 37's increment on 19-MAY-14 is: 108

...

Actual Output:

vendor 37's increment on 17-MAY-14 is:

vendor 37's increment on 19-MAY-14 is: 108

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, `last_invoice_total_sum` has no initial value, and it seems your first iteration falls in `ELSE` case, and So `invoice_row.sum_invoice - last_invoice_total_sum;`(*which is assigned to `invoice_increment` variable*)  gives `null` result.

To initialize that variable those following methods might be used :

- `last_invoice_total_sum active_invoices.invoice_total%TYPE := 0;` may
  be assigned in the declaration part

or

- `last_invoice_total_sum := 0;` before `for loop`

or

- `(last_invoice_total_sum,0)` be applied within ELSE part of IF statement as `invoice_increment := invoice_row.sum_invoice - nvl(last_invoice_total_sum,0);`

Comment: How is the result null? Its basically saying 116 - NULL  right? Shouldn't that result in an error message?

Comment: @NickJung No, doesn't give error. Arithmetical operations with a null value gives null result. As an example, `116 * null` would give null also.